# jQuery window resize - start and stop event?

Tags: jquery, resize, window, viewport

the `#right` element should auto-scroll if the viewport is greater than 960px and stop if its smaller. It already does if I start on a small viewport which gets scaled to more than 960px. If I scale it back to less than 960px it is still scrolling. Can anyone help me with that?

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if (windowSize < 960) {
      $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var space = $(window).scrollTop();   
        return 0;    
      }); 
    }
    else {
      $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var space = $(window).scrollTop();   
        return $('#right').animate({top: space}, {queue: false});    
      }); 
    }
}

// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this: [jQuery.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) in case of smaller window:

```
if (windowSize < 960) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var space = $(window).scrollTop();   
    return $('#right').stop();    
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The .stop() is working well for me. But if I scroll, the element is moving and I reszie the window to less than 960px the element is gets stuck. Do you know a way to get it to the initial-top-position?

Comment: Use `.animate()` and scroll to the top or consider [.scrollTo](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/) specific object inside `if (windowSize < 960) {` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding new scroll event on each resize. As a simple fix, unbind event:

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if (windowSize < 960) {
      $(window).off('scroll').scroll(function() {    
        var space = $(window).scrollTop(); // don't know what you are expecting here???   
        return 0;    
      }); 
    }
    else {
      $(window).off('scroll').scroll(function() {    
        var space = $(window).scrollTop();   
        $('#right').animate({top: space}, {queue: false});    
      }); 
    }
```

}

BTW, you could use `.stop()` too as in @Michal's answer.